# Is there a way to disable the 'remember me' feature in ServiceStack?

Tags: authentication, servicestack, remember-me, servicestack-auth

Obviously, not submitting that field to the login service works but anyone can override that. Is there a way to disable this feature on the server side entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is to register a custom request filter to override and ensure that it's always false, e.g

```
RegisterTypedRequestFilter<Authenticate>((req, res, dto) =>
{
    dto.RememberMe = false;
});
```

Comment: Ah. A new feature. Super convenient and I will be using these in a few places.